# external text file not loading in actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a flash file which loads text from external file, this work perfect when opening it locally on my windows 8 machine but when I upload both the flash file and external text file to the server and access it via the browser the text does not load in the flash file. Please help. Here is my code:

```
Stage.align = "TC";

Stage.scaleMode = "noScale";

url = "tfile";

loadVariablesNum(url+"_main.html", 0);

function check_loaded() {

    if (_root.file_option) {
            clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
}
intervalID = setInterval(check_loaded, 100);

_root.emp.useHandCursor = 0;
///forplayer
_root.mus = 1;
_root.n = 1;
_root.num = 1;
stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure of what you want to do with the external text file, but I normally do it using a `URLRequest` and a `URLLoader` .

For example:

```
    var textRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("myfile.txt");
    var textloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    textloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadText);//event to load text
    textloader.load(textRequest);//load text

    function loadText(event:Event):void{
    chloroText.text = textloader.data;//set the text file content as the textbox's text
    }
```